# Add-VpnConnectionRoute does not allow to add a reoute to a VPN connection

Tags: vpn, routing

I have Windows 10 Pro.

I connected to a VPN using FortiNet.

My local network addresses are `192.168.0.x` and the VPN assigned the IP `172.20.21.3` to my PC.

The problem is that I need to access the IP `192.168.21y.x` that is present in the remote network.

When I connect to a virtual machine (Windows Server) in the network where the VM belongs to I can ping to `192.168.21y.x` with no problems, however, when I try to ping from my PC, that IP is not reachable.

I tried adding the following route using Windows PowerShell:

```
Add-VpnConnectionRoute -ConnectionName 'Ethernet 3' -DestinationPrefix 192.168.21y.x/8
```

But I get this error:

> Add-VpnConnectionRoute :  Invalid parameter DestinationPrefix
> 192.168.21y.x/8. : El parámetro no es correcto. En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
>
> - Add-VpnConnectionRoute -ConnectionName 'Ethernet 3' -DestinationPrefi ...
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Ethernet 3:root/Microsoft/...ConnectionRoute) [Add-VpnConnectionRoute]    ,
>   ```
>
> CimException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WIN32 87,Add-VpnConnectionRoute

Which means that "Parameter is incorrect"

I also tried with:

```
Add-VpnConnectionRoute -ConnectionName "Ethernet 3" -DestinationPrefix "192.168.21y.x/24"
```

But this other error was shown instead:

> Add-VpnConnectionRoute :  The configuration cannot be applied to the
> local user VPN connection Ethernet 3. : El sistema no pudo encontrar
> la entrada de la libreta de teléfonos para esta conexión. En línea: 1
> Carácter: 1
>
> - Add-VpnConnectionRoute -ConnectionName "Ethernet 3" -DestinationPrefi ...
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Ethernet 3:root/Microsoft/...ConnectionRoute) [Add-VpnConnectionRoute],
>   ```
>
> CimException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VPN 623,Add-VpnConnectionRoute

Which means that the system could not find the entry of the phone book for this connection.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Add-VpnConnectionRoute` is a cmdlet that associates the route with VPN profile and installs it into a FIB as soon as this VPN connection is up.

Since your VPN profile probably cannot be named *Ethernet 3* and this is clearly a wired connection profile, you're merely doing something weird, stupid and/or hilarious.

Looks like powershell agrees with me.

Comment: Ethernet 3 is the ethernet connection associated with the VPN. Isn't this what I should use in the call to `Add-VpnConnectionRoute`